# How Can I extend The session time when there are multiple forms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-timeout

How to extend the session time. There are many form in my application like parent and child forms. So how can I make pop up to appear when session times out and the pop up should appear on the form where the user is currently in,  when popup comes I have to disable all forms like(they should be transparent (i.e) user should NOT be able to edit them).
how can i extend the session when I click on the OK button. Please can anyone suggest me

Answer (score 2):

You can have a javascript timer running on the page when it loads. When it gets close to the session time out you fire a modal popup with a button to extend the session.

Using a javascript library like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) would make the modal popup real easy to show.

The extender button can be a fake postback that automatically extend the session.

Here are some helpful links:

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1136242.aspx
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1471076.aspx
- http://forums.asp.net/p/1207721/3094847.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Any postback / request to the server will extend your session window.